# How to convert std::bind (or lambda) to std::function in deduced context?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, template-meta-programming, std-function

I am trying to convert pointer to member function (using either `std::bind` or lambdas) to a `std::function`. My attempt (following an answer from [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39182901/675100)) looks like so:

```
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
struct AsFunction :
  AsFunction<decltype(&T::operator())>
{};

template<class ReturnType, class... Args>
struct AsFunction<ReturnType(Args...)> {
  using type = std::function<ReturnType(Args...)>;
};

template<class ReturnType, class... Args>
struct AsFunction<ReturnType(*)(Args...)> {
  using type = std::function<ReturnType(Args...)>;
};

template<class Class, class ReturnType, class... Args>
struct AsFunction<ReturnType(Class::*)(Args...) const> {
  using type = std::function<ReturnType(Args...)>;
};

template<class F>
auto toFunction( F f ) -> typename AsFunction<F>::type {
  return {f};
}

struct MyStruct {
  int x,y;
  void f(int){};
};

int main(){
  MyStruct m;

  {
    // this works
    auto f = std::bind(&MyStruct::f, &m, std::placeholders::_1);
    f(2);
  }

  {
    // this doesn't
    auto f = toFunction(std::bind(&MyStruct::f, &m, std::placeholders::_1));
    f(2);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  }

  { 
    // .. neither does this
    auto f = toFunction([m](int x) mutable { m.f(x); });
    f(2);
  } 
}
```

but I get the following error messages from the compiler:

```
// first not working 
main.cpp:24:6: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted in errors seen above
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct AsFunction<std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (MyStruct::*)(int)>(MyStruct*, std::_Placeholder<1>)> >’:
main.cpp:24:6:   required by substitution of ‘template<class F> typename AsFunction<F>::type toFunction(F) [with F = std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (MyStruct::*)(int)>(MyStruct*, std::_Placeholder<1>)>]’
main.cpp:44:75:   required from here
main.cpp:4:8: error: decltype cannot resolve address of overloaded function
 struct AsFunction :
        ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:44:75: error: no matching function for call to ‘toFunction(std::_Bind_helper<false, void (MyStruct::*)(int), MyStruct*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type)’
     auto f = toFunction(std::bind(&MyStruct::f, &m, std::placeholders::_1));
                                                                           ^
main.cpp:24:6: note: candidate: template<class F> typename AsFunction<F>::type toFunction(F)
 auto toFunction( F f ) -> typename AsFunction<F>::type {
      ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:24:6: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted in errors seen above

// second non working braces with lambda
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct AsFunction<void (main()::<lambda(int)>::*)(int)>’:
main.cpp:4:8:   required from ‘struct AsFunction<main()::<lambda(int)> >’
main.cpp:24:6:   required by substitution of ‘template<class F> typename AsFunction<F>::type toFunction(F) [with F = main()::<lambda(int)>]’
main.cpp:50:55:   required from here
main.cpp:5:23: error: ‘operator()’ is not a member of ‘void (main()::<lambda(int)>::*)(int)’
   AsFunction<decltype(&T::operator())>
                       ^~
main.cpp:50:55: error: no matching function for call to ‘toFunction(main()::<lambda(int)>)’
     auto f = toFunction([m](int x) mutable { m.f(x); });
                                                       ^
main.cpp:24:6: note: candidate: template<class F> typename AsFunction<F>::type toFunction(F)
 auto toFunction( F f ) -> typename AsFunction<F>::type {
      ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:24:6: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted in errors seen above
```

Comment: @Holt I think OP wants to deduce the result type and types of arguments. Am I right?

Comment: @W.F. exactly ( I want to manipulate them later)

Comment: Okay, and do you really need to use a *lambda* or `std::bind`? Wouldn't `toFunction(&MyStruct::f, &m)` be ok? Since "lambda type" and the return of `std::bind` are implementation-defined, it is always hard to use them to deduce template arguments...

Comment: @Holt I need placeholders because this `f` method is a callback in my original code (way more complicated) where I get some value to that callback.

Comment: @Patryk You can forward placeholders (and other things) from `toFunction` to `std::bind`, and it is much more easier to deduces `Args` from a pointer to member function than from `std::bind`'s return type, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to deduce arguments from a lambda or a `std::bind` return type, so you may want to delay the bind inside `toFunction`, e.g. with:

```
template<typename C, typename Ret, typename... Args, typename... BArgs>
auto toFunction(Ret (C::*f)(Args...), BArgs&&... bargs) {
  return std::function<Ret(Args...)>(std::bind(f, std::forward<BArgs>(bargs)...));
}
```

This way, you can retrieve a `std::function` using:

```
auto f = toFunction(&MyStruct::f, &m, std::placeholders::_1);
f(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overkilling this a bit. If you really want an explicit `std::function` type for your `f`, you can just specify it directly with some trickery:

```
int main(){
  MyStruct m;

  {
    std::function<decltype(std::declval<MyStruct>().f(int()))(int)> f(std::bind(&MyStruct::f, &m, std::placeholders::_1));
    f(2);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  }
}
```

Having said that, the simplest thing by far is to simply use `auto f` without specifying a type. I'm assuming you've already thought of that and it won't do in your case, but I say this just in case anyway.

Comment: I think this way you would need to know of the types of the arguments...

Comment: Ah I see. Well the above can just as easily be moved to your `toFunction` call with templated types to give you the argument types. Let me modify answer to demonstrate