# Deducing return and parameter type from std::function passed as a template function argument?

Tags: c++, templates, std-function

I've been looking around SO for a while now but cannot find quite the answer that I am looking for - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39173519/8445453) is probably the closest to what I am thinking.

In a sentence: is it possible to declare a template function that takes a parameter of an `std::function` and deduce template parameters for both the return type and the parameter types of the function? Example:

```cpp
//this works to pass the std::function in
template<class T>
void doSomething(std::function<T> f) {
    f();
}

//this is more what i am looking for - can R and P be deduced automatically - does not work!
template<class R, class P>
void doSomethingElse(std::function<R(P)> f) {
    f();
}
```

Is this because the function signature or function type is considered one thing in itself, and as such cannot be "broken" up? I realise there are `decltype` and `std::result_of` but cannot think how I might use them here.

As an additional point, how might I extend the second example to have multiple parameters and deduction, using variadic templates?

Comment: `template<class R, class P> void doSomethingElse(std::function<R(P)>);` is fine, (but actually expects `std::function`, **not** any functors as lambda).

Comment: Except for the fact that `f()` would need an argument, this works in principal : https://godbolt.org/z/hgx5te. What seems to be the problem? Did you maybe try to pass it a lambda expression? Maybe you should share a [MCVE] to better illustrate the question.

Comment: And `template<class R, class ... Ts> void doSomethingElse(std::function<R(Ts...)>);` for variadic version.

Comment: @Jarod42 ahh yes, for some reason I thought that I was getting around this by using a function pointer, something like `auto func = static_cast<int(*)(int)>([](int x) { return x; });`  but obviously if there is still an implicit conversion to `std::function` from there. Thanks!

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I didn't try a lambda - I knew that wouldn't work, but didn't think about function pointer. The point of the question was - can you get the return type and the parameter types out of the std::function - which as your reply and the answer shows you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<class R, class P>
void doSomethingElse(std::function<R(P)> f) {
    f(P{});
}
```

Will work, but it only works if you pass a `std::function` to the function and that function has one non void parameter.  This is kind of limiting though.  You can use

```
template<class R, class... Args, class... Ts>
void doSomethingElse(std::function<R(Args...)> f, Ts&&... args) {
    f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Which will take any `std::function` and the arguments for it and calls them as if you did it in the call site.  This is still limiting though because the call site requires you use a `std::function` so you can't pass it anything implicitly convertible to a `std::function`.

With C++17 and [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) (CTAD) this is no longer an issue though.  We can create an overload that takes any type, and then construct a std::function using CTAD to fill in the types for us.  That would look like

```
template<class Func, class... Args>
void doSomethingElse(Func&& f, Args&&... args) {
    doSomethingElse(std::function{std::forward<Func>(f)}, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<class R, class... Args, class... Ts>
void doSomethingElse(std::function<R(Args...)> f, Ts&&... args) {
    f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

And now anything that isn't a `std::function` will go to `void doSomethingElse(Func&& f, Args&&... args)`, get converted to a `std::function`, and get passed to `void doSomethingElse(std::function<R(Args...)> f, Args&&... args)` so you can use the return type and argument(s) type(s) in there.

Comment: @NathanOliver why is CTAD so important here? Could I not write something like: `std::function<Func(Args...)>` to create a `std::function` and do the same?

Comment: @HarveyEllis That is problematic because the types of the function parameters might not match the types passed to `doSomethingElse`.  By using this approach you could do something like `doSomethingElse([](long long foo) {}, 5)` and a `std::function<void(long long)>` gets created instead of `std::function<void(int)>`

Comment: @NathanOliver, ah right - so if I was using C++14 or earlier I'd have to extract the actual parameters and return type from Func itself?

Comment: @HarveyEllis Yes.  You would basically have to have overloads for `doSomethingElse` that takes every function type and then give the template arguments to `std::function`.  This is a major pain and very difficult to get right.  I believe boost has stuff built for this.

Comment: @Jarod42 - why should you have two separate template parameters for the arguments you pass vs the arguments that are in the function itself? Don't you want them to be of the same type?

Comment: @HarveyEllis: Suppose you pass `std::function<void(int)>`, and `int&`, then you would have mismatch between `int` and `int&`, so deducion would fail.

Comment: @HarveyEllis Letting them be different gives you more flexibility.  Take a look at [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d47c8566e03e7628).  Using `Args` means I have to make `5` a `long long` for it to work.  Uncommenting the other function and commenting out the first one lets it work as is.