# Passing lambdas as template parameters: what type is actually deduced?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, std-function, template-argument-deduction

If I pass a lambda as a template parameter, what is the actual type of that parameter that is deduced? I have looked on the VS2017 debugger and the type of this lambda: `[](int x) {return x; }` is `filename::__I2::int<lambda>(int)`.

The reason I am asking this is because I want to pass a lambda and then create an internal `std::function` from this. Note that this relates to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55520479/8445453) and why we have to use CTAD to construct an internal `std::function` instead of just passing the template parameter to a `std::function`.

As an example, I would like to do something like the following:

```cpp
template<class Func, class... Args> 
void createStdFunc(Func f, Args... args) {
    std::function<Func> internalFunc = f; //this does not work
}

//usage
createStdFunc([](int x) {return x; }, 5);
```

However, this does not work, and I get the error `'initialising' cannot convert from 'Func' to 'std::function<Func>'`. I am not sure how the types differ and how they have changed from passing into the function to initialising the `std::function`. Please note that I do know you can use CTAD from 2017 onwards, but was wondering what a solution for 2014 and before would have been?

Comment: Every lambda has a unique type, known to the compiler, but that you cannot directly name yourself. But, they can all be converted to (properly declared) `std::function`s.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, yes - but I'd like to know why if, in the example above, if `f` is a type of Func then why can't I assign f to std::function<Func>? I'm probably understanding the types wrong.

Comment: Also, the type of a lambda is not a function type, which is required as the template argument to `std::function`.  e.g. you would need `createStdFunc<int(int)>([](int x) {return x; }, 5);` to use `int(int)` as the `Func` template parameter, not a lambda type.

Comment: @DanielSchepler - ah right - so I would have to have some way of extracting the types out of the lambda to be able to do this? I wonder how CTAD does this then.

Comment: What do you actually want to _do_ with the `std::function`? You're getting all of the arguments at the same time - do you want to just lazily bind them all (e.g. `internalFunc` should take no arguments?) or what? It's a little odd for me to see both `std::function` and all the arguments - so I'd like to know what the actual problem you're trying to solve is.

Answer (score 3):

In C++14 you can use return type deduction to figure out function signature, this implies that types of arguments passed into `createStdFunc` match:

```
template<class Func, class... Args> 
void createStdFunc(Func f, Args... args) {
    std::function<std::result_of_t<Func(Args...)> (Args...)> internalFunc{f}; //this does work
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename R, typename T, typename ... As>
constexpr std::function<R(As...)> getFuncType (R(T::*)(As...) const);

template <typename F, typename ... As>
void createStdFunc (F const & f, As ... as)
 {
   decltype(getFuncType(&F::operator()))  internalFunc { f };

   internalFunc(as...);
 }

int main ()
 {
   createStdFunc([](int x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }, 5);
 }
```

Maybe also through a `using`

```
template <typename F>
using funcType = decltype(getFuncType(&F::operator()));

template <typename F, typename ... As>
void createStdFunc (F const & f, As ... as)
 {
   funcType<F> internalFunc { f };

   internalFunc(as...);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem inside your code is that `Func` is not a function type. It's the type of the lambda. Lambdas compile down to something like this:

```
// equivalent:
// auto my_lambda = [](int v){ return v; };

struct /* unnamed */ {
    auto operator()(int v) const { return v; }
} my_lambda;
```

The solution would be to extract the type of the `operator()` from the closure type:

```
using my_lambda_t = decltype(my_lambda);

// type: int(my_lambda_t::*)(int) const; 
auto call_operator = &decltype(my_lambda_t)::operator();
```

Then, from the type of the `operator()`, you can deduce the type of the arguments and the return type:

```
template<typename>
struct extract_types {};

template<typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct extract_types<R(C::*)(Args...) const> {
    using result = R;
    using args_types = std::tuple<Args...>;
};
```

Generalized versions of this pattern is shipped in [Boost.CallableTraits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/callable_traits/doc/html/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple trait to generalize callable types. If you handle both function pointers and anything with `operator()` (both `const` and non-`const`) you should be able to cover most use cases.

```
#include <tuple>

// For callable types
template<class T>
struct func_type : func_type<decltype(&T::operator())>{};

// For callable types' member functions (including `operator()`)
template<class T, class R, class ... Args >
struct func_type<R (T::*)(Args...) const> : func_type<R(*)(Args...)> {};

// For function pointers
template<class R, class ... Args >
struct func_type<R (*)(Args...)> {
    using type = R(Args...);
    using result = R;
    using args = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template<class T>
using func_type_t = typename func_type<T>::type;
```

`func_type_t<T>` should then give you a function type for most callable types `T`. Example uses :

```
#include <functional>

template<class Func, class... Args>
void createStdFunc(Func f, Args... args) {
    // Replaced `Func` with `func_type_t<Func>`
    std::function<func_type_t<Func>> internalFunc = f;
}

int foo(int x) { return x; }

struct bar {
    int operator()(int x) { return x; };
};


int main()
{
    // With lambda expression
    createStdFunc([](int x) {return x; }, 5);

    // With function pointer
    createStdFunc(foo, 5);

    // With std::function
    std::function<int(int)> std_func = [](int x) {return x; };
    createStdFunc(std_func, 5);

    // With a functor
    createStdFunc(bar{}, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `std::function` template expects as its argument a function type from which it infers the return and parameter type for the callable to wrap. The closure type of a lambda expression is a callable, but it's not a function type.

C++17 introduced [deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/deduction_guides) for `std::function` which allow the correct type to be deduced from any callable argument. Pre C++17, you could use a set of helper templates to deduce the correct type, for example:

```
template <typename F>
struct deduce_func_type_helper;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct deduce_func_type_helper<R(&)(Args...)>
{
    using type = std::function<R(Args...)>;
};

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct deduce_func_type_helper<R(*)(Args...)> : deduce_func_type_helper<R(&)(Args...)> {};

template <typename C, typename R, typename... Args>
struct deduce_func_type_helper<R(C::*)(Args...)> : deduce_func_type_helper<R(&)(Args...)> {};

template <typename C, typename R, typename... Args>
struct deduce_func_type_helper<R(C::*)(Args...) const> : deduce_func_type_helper<R(&)(Args...)> {};

template <typename C, typename R, typename... Args>
struct deduce_func_type_helper<R(C::*)(Args...) volatile> : deduce_func_type_helper<R(&)(Args...)> {};

template <typename F>
struct deduce_func_type_helper<F&> : deduce_func_type_helper<std::remove_cv_t<F>> {};

template <typename F>
struct deduce_func_type_helper<F&&> : deduce_func_type_helper<std::remove_cv_t<F>> {};

template <typename F>
struct deduce_func_type_helper : deduce_func_type_helper<decltype(&F::operator())> {};

template <typename F>
using func_type_t = typename deduce_func_type_helper<F>::type;
```

[live example here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAViAIzkA2AhgHaioCkATAEK8%2B5AM7oArqVTYQAcl4BmAm1RMxOANRd5AYQBmY5UQLo2LJltxcADAEFrd20WwBbAA6snmnUQCer7KbO2OoAYhb2wkSkYqhE6jiYMdgA%2BvrKyb7%2ByUjYTP6kWgK29k5uHsFa2pkBLEHqAErk6tWB2AB0Heo2pMDC4baR0bHx2IlSqQaoGX4pOXnYBTr1ELwAbACUEN29HW3r/XYA7EU26mfqYsJKwM0zXgAi6pGYICBpscZslcvbwrv78ks8hOXEO90K9hKLncLE8lRatWCjVu/lauy6PT6gIiURicQSSQm6Wq2Vy%2BW%2BEAAVJtfv8LOoQCMxil3tMsnNyUsVjwNltMXTAZpjqDwcDIY5oeUvFUZq11Nomgi6sile1Or8DoM8UzCaySRyFhTtK9qXydh0AbgGTrxnqZqT5ottMs1jT%2BRb6aCBGCIcUJWVYRVvLLEfLFSHleHUYj0RrsQNccMCbbJmzZmTDVzjSBTbSLeoMGxIvTGcmWan9RmnS6eW7zXtPcKfWK/TZSjC4cHo3UFSiapG%2B2j1ZjNYn8aNdRX7QbqxBs7n3Xt1AA3dAeAhMbAlm3l4nTqsU11mv4ewVekW%2BhxtyWB6Wq0Kjobj5lEqaVx2VMI87dl19ph2ctozyvKQLjoMuKSoMuGSfuEZ5NqKIL%2Bh2QYyt2wRhPGNhakmE4pnu7IHjoX6rGsP54bub77h%2BOjASAoHOOBkHQUQsHYvB3qIeK14Bp2aH9hhj7ar%2BdqEY61oiVOYmATgKjVNyqwhK86D5LCZAQOslpCpxl5QrxqH3phli2Jc1zqKJKRxFojz3pJBHpjR2hGa81S6ch5SVCoLDCMIoSTE0Xk%2BbGI5nrYq4EJgBagYGADKRCYCEkwQIlyhkTy5lNHmbTqCwmLrNp9jnOZUmWZ%2Bkz0koTikKYTApagDzmbpPqtvY4WRboECVU0uhMOgsIAkh2FjvKkLCrYRVteZnVsEQ3W9f1TVca2lXqM4LBKBpo0nEVqDRU4cUJUlXAAKwCMd9zTbN5nzUQ%2BwIQNhXnLt2CxfFdUQLoD3jU9e3YAd71rJ9i32DI6zMLIx0yOQbCyFYUPoLI2iCIITziJIFQ8PI9BQ0QsOg2DADWIDHQAnG09AU6sJP0IcVgACyHKsAAc9A8ODMh01DzgMFYVjQ3j5AIzIUPCCAfO4zIcNg3AsAoBgbgbgslDUPLriK6QaCsBwGTRGwBPkLoG5VaLEAAEYC6bSi5T4sjY%2BQ8tBDNADybBMDbktQzga0cJuAuEKBHwQaLHvkNgAAe2CoGITi21DlW5ALTAEKbpDW9oWDSDIdtRAQ3NZ6DzDsJwyP8Mwyei5AYMqUYJjBwAtM81ncPwgj0HT6h1078gi2jUgMGDTAQ1DMMh0LYdM6sderO3XkcOoEC4nr%2BUQPgxBkJomOMPK6AK5upAb1j%2BVIy3/A43jmnkETdNWG0TN3/IVhMzwJPHZvd/s5z/Oj7IIti%2BQEtSwHrIHgXMQCrGOm0Emhx5A8GOtfCe9AWY8EOF/OGgsf7/3PuQGWyAQDiCIK4aOysICq3VgwUOhASAa0YAAd1Tq4WOQCZCQ1QfDWQCh6DqBocQJA6hx6T2ngWLWNwF66wJusM%2BHsL45BYDgDWGkP6gPkHTNoVgeSHDpqTeg8gWZM0OGzEeaCha/3FufJh3dWHoOFpgqRYMIKkCuCYEAdMgA%3D)

Note that above example is not complete; it's missing some specializations, e.g., for all possible combinations of `const`, `volatile`, and different ref qualifiers. So this can get quite verbose, you will probably want to go with C++17 if you can…